# How to renconcile between 'testing on day of judgement' and Abdullah bin Abdul Mutallib being a dweller of hell?

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, hadith-interpretation, jahannam

1. As per hadith, abdullah and aminah will be dwellers of hell.
2. As per surah mulk angels ask " did no warner come to you (hell entering people)"
3. Testing on day of judgement of people between fatrah.(period between  prophets)
4. Glad tidings of hell to dead kaafir when we pass by their grave. Sahih as per Albani.
5. Allah in Quran, we do not punish a people until we send messenger.

How do i reconcile between these 5 in the light of covenant between mankind and Allah when he brought forth the progeny of Adam.

Answer (score 1):

They can be reconciled by either one of the following explanations:

1. Abdullah bin Abdul Muttalib is not a dweller of hell. The [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:203) (أبي وأباك في النار) can be interpreted to refer to one of the uncles of the Prophet ﷺ who received his dawah and then disbelieved in him, e.g. Abu Lahab or Abu Talib. That is because in Arabic the paternal uncle can be called أب, such as in the Quran [2:133](https://quran.com/2/133?translations=20).

   > العرب تسمي العم أبا
   >
   > The Arabs call the paternal uncle as father
   >
   > <sup>—  [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya133.html#qortobi), [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura2-aya133.html#baghawy) etc.</sup>
2. The message of previous Abrahamic religion had reached Abdullah and evidence was established against him. Hence he would be among the dwellers of hell for denying it. See [Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/559).
3. Abdullah will fail the test on the day of judgement and hence be among the dwellers of hell. See [Ibn Kathir](https://shamela.ws/index.php/book/4445/1523).
4. The view that the ahl al-fitrah will be tested on the day of judgement is not correct. Actually there are different madhabs on their fate. Among them is that they shall be forgiven, and among them is that they will not be forgiven and will be in hell. The hadith could be taken as evidence for the last madhab.

Reference: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/10467/

Comment: My father and your father are in hell. Is the hadith wording